# Incorrectly nested style tag found then seeding database in laravel

Tags: laravel, seeding

then I try to seed my laravel database i get: ***Incorrectly nested style tag found.***
I have done everything as is required in documentation and can't understand the reason of this error

```
Symfony\Component\Console\Exception\InvalidArgumentException  : Incorrectly nested style tag found.

  at C:\wamp\www\advoca\vendor\symfony\console\Formatter\OutputFormatterStyleStack.php:75
    71|                 return $stackedStyle;
    72|             }
    73|         }
    74|
  > 75|         throw new InvalidArgumentException('Incorrectly nested style tag found.');
    76|     }
    77|
    78|     /**
    79|      * Computes current style with stacks top codes.
```

Whats wrong?
my DAtabase seeder:

```
class DatabaseSeeder extends Seeder
{
    public function run()
    {
        $this->call([
            QueryTemplate_seeder::class,
        ]);
    }
}
```

my QueryTemplate_seeder :

```
<?php



class QueryTemplate_seeder extends Seeder
{

    public function run()
    {
           //1
           DB::table('query_templates')->insert([

            'content' => 'some string content',
            'queryid' => 111111,
            'customerId'=>'sdfsgdgsdgdsg'
        ]);

         //2
         DB::table('query_templates')->insert([

            'content' => 'some string content',
            'queryid' => 123456,
            'customerId'=>'sdgsdgsdgsdgfsdg'

        ]);

         //3
         DB::table('query_templates')->insert([

            'content' => 'some string content',
            'queryid' => 112233,
            'customerId'=>'adsgdfgsdfgdgs'
        ]);
    }
}
```

please help!!!

Comment: Is "some string content" contains some html codes or text having single quote inside?

Comment: yes i guess it was the problem)

Answer (score 0):

I solved problem by deleting all seeds and creating them again. and everything worked!